# GTK pass user data to callback using Glade

Tags: c, callback, gtk, signals, glade

I notice that Glade only allows you to set an object to be passed within the user data part of a GTK callback.

Is there any way I can pass an integer value instead?

I have a set of menu items which I would like to point at the same callback function, however for a small section of the code I need to identify which menu item was the one which called the callback.

Note:
All my signals are setup automatically with glade_xml_signal_autoconnect, and I would perfer to keep it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion with respect to glade and callbacks one have to say goodbye to the notion of passing just one single element to callbacks. And thus stop using `glade` in order to configure the user data that is passed to a specific callback.

I get used to pass a struct named `App` to all callbacks that contains a pointer to every ui element that is loaded from the ui definitions file and already instantiated by `GtkBuilder`. This also stops the tedious task in `glade` of clicking back and forth between widgets only to set up the user data of the callbacks. In addition to the ui elements, most of the time this struct contains further elements that are important at runtime on application level.

A benefit of this approach is that you are not tempted to think about how to implement an individual callback that should act upon more than one element which is often the case. Some people tackle this by grouping the widgets of interest into a container. In order to pass all widgets to the callback they just pass the container. Then in the callback they get the widgets by calling `gtk_container_get_children` or similar functions. This approach makes callbacks illegible and reduce the fun while editing the code.

If every callback has all elements available that should be manipulated at runtime you don't have to care about implementing a single callback since every callback shares the same structure.

Further i created a helper macro that defines a pointer to an already instantiated element with the name of its glade id. This way the elements definitions in the code are always in sync with those that are displayed in glade. That makes renaming of widgets very easy (substitute the name in all sources + the glade file).

To illustrate this approach i have appended files of a sample program. Don't be scared of the number of files. Dividing a program into logical units/modules makes programming much simpler. To get a quick view of the whole project i created a git repository on github:

> https://github.com/o8i12398z12h9h/gtk-sample-app

Just compare my `callbacks.c` with your callback file(s). I would be interested to know how they compare with respect to legibility and structure and taking into account that you may have the element-ids from `glade` still in mind.

---

`callbacks.c`:

```
#include "app.h"

void
button1_clicked_cb (GtkButton * button, App * app)
{
    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkEntry, entry1);

    if (gtk_entry_get_text_length (entry1) == 0)
        gtk_entry_set_text (entry1, "test");
    else
        gtk_entry_set_text (entry1, "");
}

void
button2_clicked_cb (GtkButton * button, App * app)
{
    gboolean active;

    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkSpinner, spinner1);
    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkWidget, eventbox1);

    g_object_get (G_OBJECT (spinner1), "active", &active,
                  NULL);

    if (active) {
        gtk_spinner_stop (spinner1);
        gtk_widget_override_background_color (eventbox1,
                                              GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL,
                                              app->
                                              active_color);
    }
    else {
        gtk_spinner_start (spinner1);
        gtk_widget_override_background_color (eventbox1,
                                              GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL,
                                              app->
                                              inactive_color);
    }
}

void
button3_clicked_cb (GtkButton * button, App * app)
{
    GdkRGBA bg = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };

    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkWidget, eventbox1);

    gtk_widget_override_background_color (eventbox1,
                                          GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL,
                                          &bg);
}

void
button4_clicked_cb (GtkButton * button, App * app)
{
    const gchar *str;

    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkLabel, label1);

    str = gtk_label_get_text (label1);

    if (strcmp (str, "label") == 0) {
        gtk_label_set_text (label1, "NewText");
    }
    else {
        gtk_label_set_text (label1, "label");
    }
}

void
button5_clicked_cb (GtkButton * button, App * app)
{
    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkWidget, button1);
    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkWidget, button2);
    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkWidget, button4);

    g_signal_emit_by_name (button1, "clicked", app);
    g_signal_emit_by_name (button2, "clicked", app);
    g_signal_emit_by_name (button4, "clicked", app);
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "app.h"

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    App *app;

    app = (App *) g_new (App, 1);

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    app_init (app);

    GET_UI_ELEMENT (GtkWidget, window1);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window1);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

`app.c`:

```
#include "app.h"

GObject *
app_get_ui_element (App * app, const gchar * name)
{
    const gchar *s;
    GSList *list;

    list = app->objects;

    do {
        s = gtk_buildable_get_name (list->data);

        if (strcmp (s, name) == 0) {
            return list->data;
        }

    } while (list = g_slist_next (list));

    return NULL;
}

void
app_init_colors (App * app)
{
    GdkRGBA active_color = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    GdkRGBA inactive_color = { 0, 1, 0, 1 };

    app->active_color = g_new0 (GdkRGBA, 1);
    app->inactive_color = g_new0 (GdkRGBA, 1);

    app->active_color = gdk_rgba_copy (&active_color);
    app->inactive_color = gdk_rgba_copy (&inactive_color);
}


void
app_init (App * app)
{
    GError *err = NULL;

    app->definitions = gtk_builder_new ();

    gtk_builder_add_from_file (app->definitions,
                               UI_DEFINITIONS_FILE, &err);

    if (err != NULL) {
        g_printerr
            ("Error while loading app definitions file: %s\n",
             err->message);
        g_error_free (err);
        gtk_main_quit ();
    }

    gtk_builder_connect_signals (app->definitions, app);

    app->objects = gtk_builder_get_objects (app->definitions);

    app_init_colors (app);
}
```

`app.h`:

```
#ifndef __APP__
#define __APP__

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define UI_DEFINITIONS_FILE "ui.glade"

#define GET_UI_ELEMENT(TYPE, ELEMENT)   TYPE *ELEMENT = (TYPE *) \
                                            app_get_ui_element(app, #ELEMENT);

typedef struct app_
{
    GtkBuilder *definitions;
    GSList *objects;

    GdkRGBA *active_color;
    GdkRGBA *inactive_color;

} App;

void app_init (App * );
GObject * app_get_ui_element (App * , const gchar * );

#endif
```

`ui.glade`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="border_width">20</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="gtk_main_quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="row_spacing">10</property>
        <property name="column_spacing">20</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinner" id="spinner1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">2</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEventBox" id="eventbox1">
            <property name="height_request">50</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">2</property>
            <property name="width">2</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="invisible_char">•</property>
            <property name="invisible_char_set">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">2</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">3</property>
            <property name="width">2</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="buttonbox1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="spacing">10</property>
            <property name="layout_style">center</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">toggle entry</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="button1_clicked_cb" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">toggle spinner + bg</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="button2_clicked_cb" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button3">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">set bg</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="button3_clicked_cb" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">2</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button4">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">toggle label</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="button4_clicked_cb" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">3</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button5">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">toggle everything</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="button5_clicked_cb" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">4</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">5</property>
            <property name="width">4</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSeparator" id="separator1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">4</property>
            <property name="width">4</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. I had not even considered doing it this way, as you rightly stated, compared with yours, my callback.c file is a mess. I've downloaded the code you supplied and I am going to use it as a basis for writing some much cleaner code and rethinking my callbacks. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Your answer is so complicated though, and I can't see how it's better than a simple `gtk_builder_connect_signals()`.